# Unexpected results implementing stacks with linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am writting this program, and I want to understand why I am getting the wrong printing (which should de 1,2,3,4,5) gives some address instead. My `stackIsEmpty()` does not even act as it is meant to that is to stop printing values when the stack is empty. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Stacks using Structures and linked list and pointerws.

typedef struct Stack{
    //Type of the elements of the stack. Here integers
    int elem;
    //To of the stack
    struct Stack* previous;
} Stack;

void initialize(Stack *st);
void push(Stack *st, int element);
int pop(Stack *st);
int stackIsEmpty(Stack *st);

int main(){
    int i;
    Stack st;
    Stack *pt_st = &st;
    initialize(pt_st);

    //Test phase...
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        push(pt_st, i+1);

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        printf("here is one element: %d\n", pop(pt_st));
    //End of test with error!
    return 0;
}

void initialize(Stack *st){
    st = NULL;
}

void push(Stack *st, int element){
    Stack *sta = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (sta != NULL)
    {
        sta->previous = st;
        sta->elem = element;
        st = sta;
        free(sta);
    }
    else
        exit(0);
}

int pop(Stack *st){
    if(!stackIsEmpty(st))
    {
        printf("stack is empty cannot pop\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int number = st->elem;
        Stack* copy = st->previous;
        free(st);
        st = copy;
        return number;
    }
}

int stackIsEmpty(Stack *st){
    if(st == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: `st = sta;
        free(sta);`?? what is this?

Comment: I think i could put in the address of `sta` into `st`. And I free the allocated space to the variable `sta`.

Comment: did you step through the code with a debugger

Answer (score 0):

The Stack pointer `pt_st` You've created is passed by value to the functions, so the functions only modifying a local copy of it.

You can create a pointer to pointer, or make pt_st a global variable.

Your `push` function also has problems.

I've modified your code, made pt_st global, so it works now:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Stacks using Structures and linked list and pointerws.

typedef struct Stack{
    //Type of the elements of the stack. Here integers
    int elem;
    //To of the stack
    struct Stack* previous;
} Stack;

void initialize();
void push(int element);
int pop();
int stackIsEmpty();

Stack *pt_st; // made pt_st global, so functions can modify it

int main(){
    int i;
    initialize();

    //Test phase...
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        push(i+1);

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        printf("here is one element: %d\n", pop(pt_st));
    //End of test with error!
    return 0;
}

void initialize(){
    pt_st = NULL; // set it to NULL
}

void push(int element){
    Stack *sta = malloc(sizeof(Stack)); // don't need to cast malloc
    sta->elem = element;

    sta->previous = pt_st; // set sta's previous

    pt_st = sta; // point to the pushed node
}

int pop(){
    if(stackIsEmpty())
    {
        printf("pt_stack is empty cannot pop\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int number = pt_st->elem;
        Stack *temp = pt_st; // create a temp copy of the first node's address
        pt_st = pt_st->previous;
        free(temp);
        return number;
    }
}

int stackIsEmpty(){
    if(pt_st == NULL)
        return 1; // if pt_st is NULL, then the stack is empty
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read something about passing values by copy: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

`initialize` makes nothing, you pass an address (by value) so anything will be reported in you `main`. This is almost the same for every function. You also `free` immediately after having allocated a structure.
You must pass the pointer to stack by address, as the top of the stack is modified by your functions :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Stacks using Structures and linked list and pointerws.

typedef struct Stack{
    //Type of the elements of the stack. Here integers
    int elem;
    //To of the stack
    struct Stack* previous;
} Stack;

void initialize(Stack **st);
void push(Stack **st, int element);
int pop(Stack **st);
int stackIsEmpty(Stack *st);

int main(){
    int i;
    Stack *pt_st;
    initialize(pt_st);

    //Test phase...
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        push(&pt_st, i+1);

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        printf("here is one element: %d\n", pop(&pt_st));
    //End of test with error!
    return 0;
}

void initialize(Stack **st){
    *st = NULL;
}

void push(Stack **st, int element){
    Stack *sta = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (sta != NULL)
    {
        sta->previous = *st;
        sta->elem = element;
        *st = sta; // new top of stack is sta            
    }
    else
        exit(0);
}

int pop(Stack **st){
    if(!stackIsEmpty(*st))
    {
        printf("stack is empty cannot pop\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int number = (*st)->elem;
        Stack* copy = (*st)->previous;
        free(*st);
        *st = copy;
        return number;
    }
}

int stackIsEmpty(Stack *st){
    if(st == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Also try to avoid to `exit` prematurely in your functions, it is better to return an error code and let the caller take the decision, something like:

```
//pseudo code
int push(...) {
   if alloc fails return -1
   else { do the trick; return 0;
}

...
if (push(...)==-1) { print "something's wrong"; exit 0; }
```

It should be slightly different with `pop` as you need both to return a value on success and an error code on failure:

```
int pop(Stack **st,int *pop) {
    if (staksIsEmpty(st)) return -1;
    *pop = *(st.elem);
    ...
    return 0;
}

...
int value;
if (pop(&pt_st,&value)==-1) //error
```

Comment: I appriciate that remark, and i am just asking my self if it happens that the value I return is containned in the one the user provided. How should i manage to distiguish the `return integer` from the `return error`?

Comment: You're right I've made a mistake, I was talking about push, need an edit for pop...